# Generic sequence of Either to Either of sequence with preserved type

Tags: scala, scala-collections, either

I would like to have a function that converts any iterable type `C[_]` of `Either[A, B]` to `Either[C[A], C[B]]`.

I got it working but I used `asInstanceOf` method and I feel like this approach can fail in some scenario (I don't yet know what scenerio that would be since I don't quite understand `CanBuildFrom` resolving).

I think that I should implement it using custom `CanBuildFrom` but I hope there is easier way of doing that.

Here's my approach:

```
type IterableCollection[A[_], B] = A[B] with Iterable[B]

implicit class IterableEither[C[_], A, B](self: IterableCollection[C, Either[A, B]]) {
  def accumulate: Either[IterableCollection[C, A], IterableCollection[C, B]] = {
    val failures = self.collect { case x @ Left(_) => x.value }.asInstanceOf[IterableCollection[C, A]]

    if (failures.nonEmpty) Left(failures)
    else Right(self.collect { case x @ Right(_) => x.value }.asInstanceOf[IterableCollection[C, B]])
  }
}
```

I've been programming in Scala for a while but have never relied on `asInstanceOf` and thus I am a bit afraid of introducing this kind of code to a production environment. Do you guys see a way of doing this without a cast?

Comment: Isn't that just a `sequence`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one reasonably generic proposal that doesn't rely on `asInstanceOf`:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

object EitherAccumulatorExample {

  import scala.collection.{IterableLike, TraversableOnce}
  import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom  
  implicit class EitherAccumulator[C[X] <: IterableLike[X, C[X]], A, B](wrapped: C[Either[A, B]]) {
    def accumulate[CA <: TraversableOnce[_], CB](
      implicit 
      cbfA: CanBuildFrom[C[Either[A, B]], A, CA],
      cbfB: CanBuildFrom[C[Either[A, B]], B, CB]
    ): Either[CA, CB] = {
      val failures: CA = wrapped.collect{ case x @ Left(_) => x.value }(cbfA)
      if (failures.nonEmpty) Left(failures)
      else {
        val successes: CB = wrapped.collect { case x @ Right(_) => x.value }(cbfB)
        Right(successes)
      }
    }
  }

  val example = List.empty[Either[Int, Char]]
  val foo: Either[List[Int], List[Char]] = example.accumulate

  val example2 = Vector.empty[Either[String, Double]]
  val bar: Either[Vector[String], Vector[Double]] = example2.accumulate

}
```

I personally would rather propose to look at [`Validated`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/data/Validated.html), it should have a [`Traverse`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Traverse.html) instance, which in turn provides a `sequence` method, maybe this is what you want.

Comment: nice, thanks; I'm now wondering if there is some way of achieving that by using typeclasses; nonetheless going to accept this answer for now

Comment: @bottaio As I've speculated in the last sentence in my answer, you might want to take a look at `Validated` on structures that have a `Traverse`. Nazarii Bardiuk's answer does that. No problem if you unaccept and accept the other answer.

Answer (score 5):

With cats it would be a function that traverses eithers through Validated and back to Either. The reason to convert to Validated is that sequence requires Applicative instance.

```
import cats.Traverse
import cats.data.{NonEmptyList, ValidatedNel}
import cats.implicits._

def accSequence[T[_], A, B](tab: T[Either[A, B]])(implicit T: Traverse[T]): Either[NonEmptyList[A], T[B]] =
  tab.traverse[ValidatedNel[A, ?], B](_.toValidatedNel).toEither

val result: Either[NonEmptyList[Int], List[String]] = accSequence(List(Left(1), Right("A"), Left(2)))
```

Comment: yeah - this is a simple solution but you got a `NEL` in the end

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd try this with cats and came up with this:

```
object SO {

  import cats.instances.either._
  import cats.instances.list._
  import cats.syntax.traverse._

  // type alias for the Iterable C
  type C[A] = Iterable[A]

  def doIt[A, B](c: C[Either[A, B]]): Either[A, C[B]] =
    c.toList.sequence[Either[A, ?], B].map(_.to[C])
}
```

Note that I'm using Kind Projector, hence the '?'

Comment: How does it help to get the `Either[C[A], C[B]]`? It seems to throw away almost all "error-messages" in the `Left` parts.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I didn't read the question properly and missed that. Sorry.I think Nazarii's solution looks the best then.